# How I get project brief feature with 3cilcks wp theme?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

My client has a wp website. he used 3clicks wp theme and he want some feature like  http://www.logoworks.com/choose-your-project/ website for project/service sell.

any one can tell me how can I create with 3clicks wp theme...

I need woocommerce will process like this pic bellow
https://www.dropbox.com/s/uhl20gut0zjgfuh/projectPlan.jpg?dl=0

-regards

Comment: Please ask a specific question, your question is too broad.

Comment: I understand that. but if you go to this link then you can see the process how to select a project > add some Details > checkout .

Comment: I need woocommerce will process like this pic bellow https://www.dropbox.com/s/uhl20gut0zjgfuh/projectPlan.jpg?dl=0